# Why Android MNC Emulator show blank?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-mnc

I am trying to debug an MNC preview on Emulator, by after I downloaded the SDK:MNC and image and set the AVD like this:

[image: AVD setup]

And set the ram as large as possible:

[image: And set the ram as large as possible]

And choose a small resolution: 480x800 hdpi to save the memory.
But I got a blank screen of AVD, seems that not booting.
I also tried the Intel x86_64 img(**HAXM**) but NOT worked either, the blank screen:
[image: blank screen]

My Android studio version is 1.3 and My PC is intel-i5 with 8G RAM MacBookPro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lowering the ram to like 768MB the first time you start the emulator. Also are you sure you haven't disabled boot animation? what does the ADB console say?

Comment: I've disabled the boot animation.

Comment: I use the Android M (Preview) x86 image and It works!